# How to get next item from list based on some condition in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List` which contains set of time frames `(DataTime format)`. It has `StartDateTime` & `EndDateTime`. I am trying to get a next item of the list based on a condition. How can I do that?

For Example,

```
foreach (var currentTimeSlot in prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList)
{
    if (potentialStartTime > currentTimeSlot.EndDateTime)
    {
        //Skip current time slot and grab next one and so on.
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to get the first item matching a condition, like `prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList.FirstOrDefault(l => l.EndDateTime >= potentialStartTime)` ?

Comment: you can use `.Skip(1)` to skip over it, but it would be better if you can find it through some logical/conditional check

Comment: @AD.Net I tried `.Skip(1)` but it is not giving me any result.

Comment: `.Skip(1)` will only skip over it, you'll still need to do something like `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: whi not just "continue"? or i don't `understand 
foreach (var currentTimeSlot in prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList)
{
    if (potentialStartTime > currentTimeSlot.EndDateTime)
    {
        continue; //Skip current time slot and grab next one and so on.
    }
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `FirstOrDefault` in order to get the first item matching your predicate:

```
prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList
    .FirstOrDefault(x => potentialStartTime <= x.EndDateTime);
```

You can get the entire `Enumerable<T>` of items from the first matches this condition to the end using `SkipWhile`:

```
prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList
    .SkipWhile(x => potentialStartTime > x.EndDateTime);
```

The first condition is equivalent to the following code:

```
prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList
    .SkipWhile(x => potentialStartTime > x.EndDateTime)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

From what is see you try to do in the image you can do the following:

```
returnValue.IsEstimateSuccessful &= !prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList
    .SkipWhile(x => potentialStartTime > x.EndDateTime)
    .Any();
```

Comment: I like these different suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, I believe you can accomplish this with the `.FirstOrDefault` method as mentioned in comments.

```
using System.Linq;
...

var nextAvailableItem =
    prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList
    // reversing your condition above to find value I want
    // instead of specifying values I don't want
    .FirstOrDefault(x => potentialStartTime <= x.EndDateTime)
    ;

// did we find a value to match our condition?
var wasFound = nextAvailableItem != default(DateTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to loop through all the timeslots where potentialStartTime is greater than it's EndDateTime, then:

```
foreach (var currentTimeSlot in
  prepBlock.EligiblePickupTimes.BlockList.Where(x=>potentialStartTime > x.EndDateTime))
{
}
```

based on your image, I think this is what you are looking for however:

```
returnValue.IsEstimateSuccessful=!prepBlock
  .EligiblePickupTimes
  .BlockList
  .Any(x=>potentialStartTime > x.EndDateTime);
```

if returnValue.IsEstimateSuccessful is set prior to that (like if you default it to true, and many checks might turn it false):

```
returnValue.IsEstimateSuccessful&=!prepBlock
  .EligiblePickupTimes
  .BlockList
  .Any(x=>potentialStartTime > x.EndDateTime);
```